# jQuery clone likes to clone itself too much.. How to avoid?

Tags: jquery

See my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ujvHe/

When you click the +add button second time, then it makes 4 row with the fields, and when you press it third time it makes 8 rowfields.

I want to only append ONE row with those fields, when you click +add.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thats becuase you clone cloned markup again and again, try this:

```
          $(function(){
                $('#products_addlink').live('click', function(){
                    var $orig = $('.products_add:first').clone(true);

                    $('#products_adds').append($orig);
                });
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujvHe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$('.products_add:eq(0)')` instead of `$('.products_add')`

that way you only clone the first item having `products_add` class

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gRffg/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to make put the clone as a variable outside of the function that's duplicating it.

Alternatively, if you have to make a live clone each time,

```
var $orig = $('.products_add').first().clone(true);
```